# Button Click from PHP is not responding

Tags: javascript, php, button

I echo a button from a php script as following: `print'<button id="testingbtn">TEsting</button>';`

I use the id listen to the button and alert a notification message as following:

```
            $('#testingbtn').click(function(){
                alert('working');
            });
```

The thing is that i used the same method before and it worked for me on all browsers but not anymore. can someone try to help me out the problem.
thanks guys..

Comment: you have to use echo in php and not print right?

Comment: `print` and `echo` are exactly the same

Comment: have you added this on jquery(document).ready(); right?

Comment: i did guys the problem is solved; print and echo is the same ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, we assuming your 'testingbtn' is dynamically added to the screen.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "body" ).on( "click", "#testingbtn", function() {
                    alert('working');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I never recommend to do it in this way. Always put this code outside php.

HTML

```
<button id="testingbtn">TEsting</button>;
```

jQuery

```
 $('#testingbtn').click(function(){
                alert('working');
            });
```

Also make sure jQuery is included in your code.

Comment: Better put it on an external file if there are alot of JavaScript in the page!

Answer (score 3):

**Point 1:** Check whether you have included the jquery library or not.

**Point 2:** [If point 1 is OK], Where have you put your script? If you put your script before button code, than use document ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#testingbtn').click(function(){
                    alert('working');
    });
});
```

Alternately, if you want to put your code unchanged, than place your script after your button code[best practice: put them at the bottom of the page].

Answer (score 2):

I don't use print. I always use echo to show it in my html page.

```
<?php
 echo '<button id="testingbtn">TEsting</button>';
?>
```

In jquery:

```
$('#testingbtn').click(function(){
   alert('working!');
});
```

Try reading [this](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Echo_(PHP)_vs_Print_(PHP))

Comment: upvote my answer sir @moji. If this solve your problem. Tnx